# how to change a date format to a new one using proc format with the picture statement

Tags: date, sas, format

I am trying to foramt an existing date format 07/06/2020 (DDMMYYYY) to 07_06_2020 and that the output will be a string, not an int.

**my code:**

```
%LET Run_Date = %SYSFUNC(TODAY(), MMDDYY8.) ;

PROC FORMAT ;
PICTURE Runner low-high = '99_99_9999' ;
RUN ;

DATA _NULL ;
Run_Date_2 = PUT(Run_Date, Runner.) ;
CALL SYMPUT('Run_Date_2 ', Run_Date_2) ;
RUN ;

%PUT %Run_Date_2 . ;

**output**: error.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Remember to use the `datatype=date option`.

```
proc format; 
  picture dtfmt (default=10)
    low - high = '%0d_%0m_%Y' (datatype=date)
  ;
run;

data test;
   dt = "07jun2020"d;
   dt_char = put(dt, dtfmt.);
   format dt ddmmyy10.;
run;
```